# PHP MySQLi User Access Levels

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

im trying to make a user level access thing and i cant seem to get it to work basically in the db i have a column called status i want people who havent paid to be 0 then paid == 1 then admin == 2

```
<?php
require('db.php');
$user = new user;
class user
{
    function unpaid($dbcon)
    { 
        $check = $dbcon->query("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = :id");
        $row = $check->fetch_assoc();
        $status= $row['status'];
        if($status == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function paid($dbcon)
    { 
        $check = $dbcon->query("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = :id");
        $row = $check->fetch_assoc();
        $status= $row['status'];
        if($status == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function admin($dbcon)
    { 
        $check = $dbcon->query("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = :id");
        $row = $check->fetch_assoc();
        $status= $row['status'];
        if($status == 2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: its not going to work. You are using placeholders and not binding anything to it. For a quick fix, replace :id with the ID itself

Comment: you don't use `query()` with placeholders, better prepare and execute

Comment: @PhpDev what is the point in in a fix that is totally unusable ?

Comment: @JustSomeProgrammer, you just have to learn how to work with prepared statements. The code you posted simply makes no sense.